Is this construction correct? Do I have the right idea or am I mistaken?
If I wanted to say

I will open the door for you

Could I say

Se la abriré

Or would I say

La abriré por usted.

Additionally if I was to do something for someone could I always say "se lo hago"? Thanks!

Is there any reason for not translating "the door" in the Spanish versions?

You are not syaing "I will open the door for you".  You are saying "I will open it for you", where it presumably refers to the door.

Si la duda es por el uso de ‘se’, prácticamente es lo mismo. En este caso, viene a funcionar de complemento indirecto.

Abro la puerta. -> La abro.
Abro a usted. -> Le abro.
Abro la puerta a usted -> Le Se la abro.

Cuando se junta ’le‘ con ‘la’, cambiamos a ‘se la’ para evitar la cacofonía. Así que ambas están bien.
Por otro lado fijate que no usamos el futuro para ofrecernos a hacer cosas. El futuro se usa para futuros más distantes y menos certeros, si es algo muy cerca de ocurrir se usa presente. En el lenguaje escrito se suele usar más seguido el futuro, pero decir ‘yo la abriré’ en lugar de ‘yo la abro’ es ridículo al menos para mí.

It could be: I will open the door for you when you arrive. That has to be future in Spanish, too.

Como dicen ustedes, suena un poco off
